# The best solution for implement two icon enable or disable

Tags: php, html, css

I need two icon,
If is verify email, show an icon without hyberlink and set "activated" css class for green style and checked.
If is not verify email, the icon is linked to the verify page, and default is gray color style.
Which of the below solution is better and standard?

## Solution #1:

```
<a href="<?php echo ($modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail) ? 'javascript:void(0)' :
    Yii::app()->createUrl('/user/reActivate'); ?>"
   class="item<?php if($modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail) echo ' activated'; ?>">
    <div class="confirm-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Verify Email'); ?>
    </div>
</a>
<style>
.activated {
    cursor: default;
}
</style>
```

## Solution #2:

```
if($modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail) : ?>
    <div class="item activated">
        <div class="confirm-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Verify Email'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/user/reActivate'); ?>"
       class="item">
        <div class="confirm-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Verify Email'); ?>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

## Solution #3:

```
<?php if($modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail) : ?>
    <div class="item activated">
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/user/reActivate'); ?>" class="item">
<?php endif; ?>
        <div class="confirm-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Verify Email'); ?>
        </div>
<?php if($modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail) : ?>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this seems to be an opinion-based question which is off-topic.

Comment: #3             ..............

Comment: It's better to put this question is *Code Review*

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the second solution is better from readability point of view. The other solutions are too clutter. I think it would be cleaner code base if you could use a template engine.

Comment: I don't talk about readability, and I thinks the solution #3 is better for develop. Also, middle of block tag is duplicate in solution #2. Is not it?